# Why I am not able to declare my enum as a public?

Tags: java, enums

I am declaring an enum **outside the class** like below:

```
public enum CoffeeSize{SMALL, BIG, HUGE}

class Coffee{
    CoffeeSize size;
}

public class CoffeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coffee myCoffee = new Coffee();
        myCoffee.size = CoffeeSize.BIG;
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error on decalring the enum "public":

**The public type CoffeeSize must be defined in its own file.**

And I remember reading somewhere that we can declare the enum outside the class with access modifiers other than private and protected.

Can anyone please let me know why is this happening? What is wrong with my code?
And what does it mean to have my enum **"in its own file"** ?

Comment: Either, do as the compiler is telling you, put `CoffeeSize` in it's own class file (CoffeeSize.java) or move within in the `Coffer` class declaration...

Comment: "I remember reading somewhere" - I'd be willing to bet if you found this 'somewhere' you refer to, that it doesn't actually say what you think it said.

Comment: It's the same as with any other class or interface.  `javac` will not like it if you have a top-level `public class ABC` and it's not in `ABC.java`.  Same thing for enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the main reason is that your file name and public class name differs and because of that you are getting this error. The java class must contain exactly one top-level type e.g class, enum interface abstract etc. If you really wanted this enum inside this class, remove public access modifier, otherwise move it to a new file CoffeeSize.java.. hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Because in same java file there can't be two public class or enum:

In you code:
1. `public class CoffeTest {`
2. `public enum CoffeeSize{`

So You need to move one out in some other file:

Answer (score 2):

To move the enum to its own file, Make a new file named `CoffeeSize.java` and put the enum code there instead.

Comment: Ummm...  call it `CoffeeSize.java`, not `CoffeeSize.class`.  Let the Java compiler generate the `.class` files.  It's pretty good at that.

Comment: Oops you're right.  guess I need to go to bed. - fixed